# htaccess Deny from all and 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess

I want to restrict direct access to a specific directory (and all the files inside) on my local server.
The directory is: `C:/Server/www/project/html/`

I've tried the following code (.htaccess is placed in www directory - /project/html/ doesn't work too):

```
<Directory "C:/Server/www/project/html/">
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

However, it causes 500 Internal Server Error and I can't understand why.

---

Apache error log:

```
[Fri Aug 05 16:06:01 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Server/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://localhost/project/index.php?id=8
[Fri Aug 05 16:06:01 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Server/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://localhost/project/index.php?id=8
[Fri Aug 05 16:06:01 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Server/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://localhost/project/index.php?id=8
[Fri Aug 05 16:06:01 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Server/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://localhost/project/index.php?id=8
[Fri Aug 05 16:06:01 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Server/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://localhost/project/index.php?id=8
[Fri Aug 05 16:06:02 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Server/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://localhost/project/index.php?id=8
[Fri Aug 05 16:54:12 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Server/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://localhost/project/index.php?id=8
[Fri Aug 05 16:54:12 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Server/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Fri Aug 05 17:05:06 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Server/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://localhost/project/index.php?id=8
```

Comment: If you cannot place it into server config/virtual host, then get rid of the `<Directory>` and place it in .htaccess file directly (.htaccess in "C:/Server/www/project/html/").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check Apache error log for exact error description.

In any case -- the reason for this error is simple: **`<Directory>` directive CANNOT be placed in .htaccess file -- only server config or virtual host.**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

Answer (score 0):

for me it required enable headers module to apache